# php regex to get string inside a tag

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need a regex that will give me the string inside an href tag

For example i need to extract NAME in the following:

```
<a href="Somedomain1.com">NAME</a>
```

And the link inside href is not constant

My regex

```html
'/<a href="(.+)">/'
```

it give me the link inside the href only. and I don't know how to get the name of a url

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
'<a\shref="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>'

echo matches[1]; // url
echo matches[2]; // NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEx is strongly **not** recommended for parsing HTML. It would be much better if you do that by a HTML parser. [This](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is my favorite. Anyway, if you insist on to do this by RegEx, try this pattern:

```
/<a href=[^>]+>(.*)<\/a>/
```

Now, `$1` contains expected result.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fzm3Wq/1)

Comment: Thank you, for your answer that regex did work so thanks for that.
and thank you for suggesting another method as I am new to programming I didin't know other methods exists so I will definitely check the HTML Parser